# Unity Configuration in Referenced Assembly not recognized

Tags: wcf, unity-container, enterprise-library, msmq

I have a rather expensive library which I've inherited from another project. This assembly is using interception via Unity and requires an elaborate Web.config for design time configuration. I am attempting to use this assembly from within a MSMQ WCF Service, and I'm receiving errors when the code inside the assembly attempts to open DB connections that are hosted by Enterprise Library.

> Resolution of the dependency failed, type =
>   "ServicesImplementation.EntityMaster.IEntityRepository", name =
>   "(none)". Exception occurred while: while resolving. Exception is:
>   InvalidOperationException - The current type,
>   ServicesImplementation.EntityMaster.IEntityRepository, is an interface
>   and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

My question, is it required that I assume all configuration responsibilities from my WCF Service, or is this configuration encapsulated within the referenced assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include all configuration in your .config file. It is defalult source for application to get it config data. Also notice, that if you host in IIS, you should use web.config, if not(Windows Service or app) - use app.config. It is possible to extract section configuration to another file and reference it from your main config.

For example:

Assembly1 contains service definition and host logic.
Assembly2 actualy hosts Assembly1 service.

In this case all service configuration must reside in Assembly2 *.config file.